# Key template value 'GetItems(Id={id})' for key segment 'id' does not start with '{' or ends with '}'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to use OData in my project.

I have this class `JournalCopy` which has `ICollection<JournalItemCopy> Items` property. I tried to get this `Items` through `JournalCopy` and I want to use OData for filtering and expanding the results.

Here is my action:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("JournalRepetitives")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = TenantRequired.DefaultSchemeName)]
public class JournalRepetitivesController : ODataController
{
    private readonly ReadModelContext _readModelContext;

    public JournalRepetitivesController(ReadModelContext readModelContext)
    {
        _readModelContext = readModelContext;

    }
    private IQueryable<JournalCopy> JournalCopyQuery() => _readModelContext.Set<JournalCopy>();

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("GetItems(Id={id})")]
    public IQueryable<JournalItemCopy> GetItems([FromODataUri] string id)
    {
        return JournalCopyQuery().Where(e => e.Id == id)
            .SelectMany(e => e.Items);
    }
}
```

and I have this configuration:

```
public static class ReadModelConfiguration
{
    public static ODataModelBuilder Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntityType<JournalCopy>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        builder.EntityType<JournalItemCopy>().Collection.Function("GetItems")
            .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<JournalItemCopy>(nameof(JournalItemCopy))
            .Parameter<string>("Id").Required();
    }
}
```

So when I am using **http://localhost:8000/v2/JournalRepetitives/GetItems(Id='76dee73f-8cd4-4311-9708-4701c3d2d017')** to call the Api in postman but I got **The path template 'JournalRepetitives/GetItems(Id={id})' on the action 'GetItems' in controller 'JournalRepetitives' is not a valid OData path template. Key template value 'GetItems(Id={id})' for key segment 'id' does not start with '{' or ends with '}'**. but I don't know its problem.

[image]

Any Idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used OData routing, but based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/attribute-routing) I think it could be a few things:

1. Remove the quotes in your URL. You usually don't use quotes in URLs.

```
http://localhost:8000/v2/JournalRepetitives/GetItems(Id=76dee73f-8cd4-4311-9708-4701c3d2d017)
```

2. You might need to remove the `Id=`. So your route should be:

```
[ODataRoute("GetItems({id})")]
```

And your URL would look like:

```
http://localhost:8000/v2/JournalRepetitives/GetItems(76dee73f-8cd4-4311-9708-4701c3d2d017)
```

3. I seem to remember an issue with Postman where it would URL encode parentheses even though it doesn't need to, so try disabling URL encoding in Postman. In Postman, under the URL, click on Settings, then turn off "Encode URL automatically".

[image: 1]